# Mongoose Unique Email Address Validation

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to enforce a Unique Email address when a user signs up. But Mongoose does not seem to be obeying the `unique: true` flag in my schema.

```
// NPM Packages
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please enter First Name'],
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please enter Last Name'],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      match: [
        /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
        'Please add a valid email address.',
      ],
      required: [true, 'Please enter Email Address'],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please enter a password'],
      minlength: [6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters'],
      select: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

// Encrypt User Password
UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10); // Recommended in bcryptjs doc
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
```

Comment: adding `unique` is like adding `index`. Try restarting the mongo server and try inserting again.

Comment: @Himakar so using unique wont work on real-time?

Comment: When you are adding createIndex, unique, etc you will have to restart to reflect the changes.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5050#issuecomment-287263633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dropDups in your schemas like

```
email: {
  type: String,
  match: [
    /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\. 
 [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
    'Please add a valid email address.',
  ],
  required: [true, 'Please enter Email Address'],
  unique: true,
  lowercase: true,
  dropDups: true
}
```

Comment: What is dropDups for? @Avid Programmer could you elaborate?